# How to edit text in a function cell in Numbers for Mac

Tags: excel, macos, numbers

My PC isn't set up at the moment so I'm having to do a bunch of excel work on my mac using Numbers. I have a function applied to split addresses into 4 different columns, however I need to change a few minor details in some. Since all of the data is output from functions I don't know how to change the data without having to delete the function and retype the cell from scratch.

In Excel I know theres a way to kind of rasterize the data and make it editable. But how do I do this in Numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just highlight the cells you're interested in changing, and paste them in a new column with "paste formula results" from the edit menu.

The new column has plain values.